# Android Studio Instrumented Tests - how to handle permission dialogs

Tags: android, testing, automation

I am writing instrumented test automation for an Android app.  The app pops up several native permission dialogs during start-up (like, allow access to Camera) which do not register in the Espresso Test Recorder.  How do I handle these dialogs (click Allow) so I can get the app to launch? Or is there a way to grant the app permissions when installing, so the dialogs won't show up?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do it - Espresso can't handle multiple apps, but uiautomator can!  And it's also packaged in with Android Studio.  Here's a link: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html#run